# Call const function address passed to gcc inline assembler (avr-gcc)

Tags: c++, gcc, avr, inline-assembly, avr-gcc

I'm writing an RPC library for AVR and need to pass a function address to some inline assembler code and call the function from within the assembler code. However the assembler complains when I try to call the function directly.

This minimal example test.cpp illustrates the issue (in the actual case I'm passing args and the function is an instantiation of a static member of templated class):

```
void bar () {
    return;
}

void foo() {
    asm volatile (
        "call %0" "\n"
        :
        : "p" (bar)
    );
}
```

Compiling with `avr-gcc -S test.cpp -o test.S -mmcu=atmega328p` works fine but when I try to assemble with `avr-gcc -c test.S -o test.o -mmcu=atmega328p` avr-as complains:

```
test.c: Assembler messages:
test.c:38: Error: garbage at end of line
```

I have no idea why it writes "test.c", the file it is referring to is test.S, which contains this on line 38:

```
call gs(_Z3barv)
```

I have tried all even remotely sensible constraints on the paramter to the inline assembler that I could find [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints) but none of those I tried worked.

I imagine if the gs() part was removed, everything should work, but all constraints seem to add it. I have no idea what it does.

The odd thing is that doing an indirect call like this assembles just fine:

```
void bar () {
    return;
}

void foo() {
    asm volatile (
        "ldi r30, lo8(%0)" "\n"
        "ldi r31, hi8(%0)" "\n"
        "icall" "\n"
        :
        : "p" (bar)
    );
}
```

The assembler produced looks like this:

```
ldi r30, lo8(gs(_Z3barv))
ldi r31, hi8(gs(_Z3barv))
icall
```

And avr-as doesn't complain about any garbage.

Comment: Related: [Direct C function call using GCC's inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3467180)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code:

**Issue 1: Wrong Constraint**

The correct constraint for a call target is `"i"`, thus known at link-time.

**Issue 2: Wrong % print-modifier**

In order to print an address suitable for a call, use `%x` which will print a plain symbol without `gs()`.  Generating a linker stub at this place by means of `gs()` is not valid syntax, hence *"garbage at end of line"*. Apart from that, as you are calling `bar` *directly*, there is no need for linker stub (at least not for this kind of symbol usage).

**Issue 3: `call` instruction might not be available**

To factor out whether a device supports `call` or just `rcall`, there is `%~` which prints a single `r` if just `rcall` is available, and nothing if `call` is available.

**Issue 4: The Call might clobber Registers or have other Side-Effects**

It's unlikely that the call has no effects on registers or on memory whatsoever.  If you description of the inline asm does not match some side-effects of the code, it's likely that you will get wrong code sooner or later.

**Taking it all together**

Let's assume you have a function `bar` written in assembly that takes two 16-bit operands in R22 and R26, and computes a result in R22.  This function does not obey the avr-gcc C/C++ [calling convention](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Calling_Convention), so inline assembly is one way to interface to such a function.  For `bar` we cannot write a correct prototype anyways, so we just provide a prototype so that we can use symbol `bar`.  Register X has constraint `"x"`, but R22 has no own register constraint, and therefore we have to use a local asm register:

```cpp
extern "C" void bar (...);

int call_bar (int x, int y)
{
    register int r22 __asm ("r22") = x;
    __asm ("%~call %x2"
           : "+r" (r22)
           : "x" (y), "i" (bar));
    return r22;
}
```

Generated code for ATmega32 + optimization:

```
_Z8call_barii:
    movw r26,r22
    movw r22,r24
    call bar
    movw r24,r22
    ret
```

**So what's that "generate stub" `gs()` thing?**

Suppose the C/C++ code is taking the address of a function.  The only sensible thing to do with it is to call that function, which will be an indirect call in general. Now an indirect call can target 64KiW = 128KiB at most, so that on devices with > 128KiB of code memory, special means must be taken to indirectly call a function beyond the 128KiB boundary.  The AVR hardware features an SFR named `EIND` for that purpose, but problems using it are obvious. You'd have to set it prior to a call and then reset it somehow somewhere; all evil things would be necessary.

avr-gcc takes a different approach: For each such address taken, the compiler generates `gs(func)`.  This will just resolve to `func` if the address is in the 128KiB range. If not, `gs()` resolves to an address in section `.trampolines` which is located close to the beginning of flash, i.e. in the lower 128KiB.  `.trampolines` containts a list of direct `JMP`s to targets beyond the 128KiB range.

Take for example the following C code:

```c
extern int far_func (void);

int main (void)
{
    int (*pfunc)(void) = far_func;
    __asm ("" : "+r" (pfunc)); /* Forget content of pfunc. */
    return pfunc();
}
```

The __asm is used to keep the compiler from optimizing the indirect call to a direct one. Then run

```
> avr-gcc main.c -o main.elf -mmcu=atmega2560 -save-temps -Os -Wl,--defsym,far_func=0x24680
> avr-objdump -d main.elf > main.lst
```

For the matter of brevity, we just define symbol `far_func` per command line.
The assembly dump in `main.s` shows that `far_func` might require a linker stub:

```
main:
    ldi r30,lo8(gs(far_func))
    ldi r31,hi8(gs(far_func))
    eijmp
```

The final executable listing in `main.lst` then shows that the stub is actually generated and used:

```
main.elf:     file format elf32-avr

Disassembly of section .text:
...

000000e4 <__trampolines_start>:
  e4:   0d 94 40 23     jmp 0x24680 ; 0x24680 <far_func>

...

00000104 <main>:
 104:   e2 e7           ldi r30, 0x72   ; 114
 106:   f0 e0           ldi r31, 0x00   ; 0
 108:   19 94           eijmp
```

main loads Z=0x0072 which is a word address for byte address 0x00e4, i.e. the code is indirectly jumping to 0x00e4, and from there it jumps directly to 0x24680.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I eventually got this working using the X (non) constraint and %c operand modifier, but I never got around to updating this question. I see now that the i constraint works as well and is probably more correct.

Comment: Yes, constraint `"X"` means *"no constraint on operand at all"*.  The difference between `%c` print modifier and `%x` is that the former is generic gcc, whereas the latter is specific to target avr.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `call` requires a constant, known-at-link-time value. The `"p"` constraint does not include that semantics; it would also allow a pointer from a variable (e.g. `char* x`), which `call` cannot handle. (I seem to remember that sometimes gcc is clever enough to optimize in such a way that "p" does work here - but that's basically undocumented behavior and non-deterministic, so better not count on it.)

If the function you're calling actually is compile-time constant you can use `"i" (bar)`. If it's not, then you have no other choice than using `icall` as you already figured out.

Btw, the AVR section of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints documents some more, AVR-specific constraints.

Comment: No, the assress of a call need not be known at assembly-time.  It's perfectly fine to have a symbol as a call target.

Comment: Yes, link-time constant vs. assemble-time constant is a subtle but sometimes important distinction.  Both can get called compile-time constants. `"i"` allows an assemble-time or link-time constant (at least on most ISAs).

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts You're right :) I'll change the wording.

Answer (score -1):

I've tries various ways of passing a C function name to inline ASM code without success. However I did find a workaround, which *seems* to provide the desired result.

---

**Answer to the question:**

As explained on https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html you can assign a ASM name to a C function in a prototype declaration:

```
void bar (void) asm ("ASM_BAR");    // any name possible here
void bar (void)
{
    return;
}
```

Then you can call the function easily from your ASM code:

```
asm volatile("call ASM_BAR");
```

---

**Use with library functions:**

This approach does not work with library functions, because they have their own prototype declarations. To call a function like `system_tick()` of the `time.h` library more efficiently from an ISR, you can declare a helper function. Unfortunately GCC does not apply the inline setting to calls from ASM code.

```
inline void asm_system_tick(void) asm ("ASM_SYSTEM_TICK") __attribute__((always_inline));
void asm_system_tick(void)
{
    system_tick();
}
```

In the following example GCC does only generate push/ pop instructions for the surrounding code, not for the function call! Note that `system_tick()` is specifically designed for `ISR_NAKED` and does all required stack operations on its own.

```
volatile uint8_t tick = 0;
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect)
{
    tick++;
    if (tick > 127)
    {
        tick = 0;
        asm volatile ("call ASM_SYSTEM_TICK");
    }
}
```

Because the inline attribute does not work, each function call takes 8 additional cpu cycles. Compared to 5632 CPU cycles required for push/ pull operations with a normal function call (44 CPU cycles for each run of the ISR) it is still a very impressive improvement.