# Accessing values of process independent registers in c

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

Many registers like data registers contain values corresponding to the current process being executed. But, there are some registers which are common for all the processes

I want read access to some registers which are non process specific and can be accessed from 2 different processes and still be able to get the same value.

I need the code for the x86-64 architecture. (The 3 commands uname -m,-p,-i return x86_64, when typed on my desktop)

Thanks.

Comment: OK, you need the user manual for your processor, the source code for your OS, an assembler and some luck.  Note that this mechanism, even if it existed, is not typically how processes communicate.  What would happen if three processes wished to comunicate with this mechanism?

Comment: Can you define which registers are 'control registers' ? Because PC and SP definitely contain different values for different processes.

Comment: This is usually done using system calls, so that the code will be portable between different processors.

Comment: Please pick one of C and Python. I won't play the game “that's not the programming language I really wanted” with you.

Comment: @fuz  picked 'C'. Actually, I am okay with C or python, but since I am asked to pick one, I chose C.

Comment: @MagedElghareib Removed the "control registers" part. I was assuming that control register values are independent of process being executed.

Comment: @user1877095 For what architecture would you like to read control registers? Every architecture has different control registers, so answers are going to differ.

Comment: I have changed “64 bit architecture” to “x86-64 architecture.” x86-64 is one of many 64 bit architectures, but from your post it is the most likely one. Good! Now I can prepare an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x86-64 architecture has quite a few such control registers. Most of them cannot be read without elevated privileges, those that can are marked. You might want to  read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register) for a detailed description on the bits in each register.

On Linux, you can obtain the relevant elevated privileges using the `iopl` system call. `iopl(3)` gives you all privileges you need.

- The flags register contains information about recent arithmetic operations as well as some configuration. It can be read with the `pushf` instruction without special permissions. Read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) for more details.
- The segment registers `cs`, `ds`, `es`, `ss`, `fs`, and `gs` contain segment selectors. On modern operating systems, these are usually fixed for all processes and can be read using `mov r16,segr` without elevated privileges.
- The cr0 register contains configuration pertaining memory protection. Its low 16 bits can be read by any process using the `rmsw` instruction, the remaining bits can be read with elevated privileges using `mov r32,cr0` as can all other control registers.
- The cr2 register contains the address of the last page fault.
- The cr3 register contains the address of the page directory.
- The cr4 register contains additional CPU configuration.
- The cr8 register contains information about task priority

There are also a bunch of model-specific registers which can be read with the `rmsr` instructions.

To read these registers, use inline assembly. Here is inline assembly for all registers previously mentioned. For reading the `rflags` register, also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39160450/417501) for some caveats.

```
/* read rflags */
uint64_t rflags;
asm("pushf; popf %0" : "=rm"(rflags));

/* read segment register, replace sr with the segment you want */
uint16_t seg;
asm("mov %sr,%0" : "=rm"(seg));

/* read low bits of cr0 */
/* on some CPUs, only the low 16 bits are correct,
/* on others all 32 bit are correct */
uint32_t cr0;
asm("smsw %0" : "=r"(cr0));

/* everything below here requires elevated privileges */

/* read control register, replace cr with register name */
uint64_t cr;
asm("mov %cr,%0" : "=rm"(cr));

/* read model specific register. msr contains register number */
uint32_t msr_no = 0xC0000080, msr_hi, msr_lo;
asm("rdmsr" : "=a"(msr_lo), "=d"(msr_hi) : "c"(msr_no));
uint64_t msr_val = (uint64_)msr_hi << 32 | msr_lo;
```

Comment: Most OSes use `fs` or `gs` for thread-local storage, so whichever one they use has a per-thread value.  Also, changing a segment register in one process won't affect other processes.  Each process has its segment regs either saved/restored on context switches, or just set to what the OS thinks they should be.  (You can actually do a long jump to a different `cs` value under Linux or Windows, to run 32-bit code in a process that started in 64-bit mode.  But after an interrupt, the OS will probably return to your process in the mode it thinks it should be in, rather than saving/restoring CS)

Comment: @PeterCordes In typical usage, you never touch any segment registers and the operating system uses the same segments for all processes. To exchange the TLS segment, the operating system simply edits the ldt and reloads the segment selector. Or, on amd64, use that special instruction to reload the gs segment base.

Comment: Yeah, of course you don't usually mess with them.  But since user-space *can* mess with them, it would be a security problem for the kernel to assume that it didn't.  Thus, they have to be written on each user->kernel switch.  Not necessarily on kernel->user, though, since it's true that all processes normally get the same values (except for CS, where 32-bit processes get a different selector).

Comment: I can't believe I started talking about segments in an SO question that wasn't one of those crappy 16-bit questions.  :P  I'm really glad that the amount you need to know about them these days to optimize user-space code is currently zero (except for TLS).